# Mongo shell seemingly stops script

Tags: mongodb

I have some JavaScript that loops over a MongoDB cursor and updates each document referenced by the cursor. It seems that if there are more than 'n' documents to be updated the shell simply goes to sleep and never returns any indication of error. Here is the script I am running against the sample_mflix database that is one of the published sample databases for MongoDB:

```
var cursor = db.movies.find({plot:{$not:{$type:2}}});
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    var x = cursor.next();
    //print(typeof x.plot);
    db.movies.update({_id: x._id}, {$set: { plot: "" }});
}
```

Is there a timeout or memory limitation that I am running into?

Comment: What do you mean by "more than `n`"? What is the value of `n`?

Comment: I am not sure what "n" is I just know that it is larger than say 50.